# What guarantees does pathconf(..., _PC_NAME_MAX) provide?

Tags: posix, readdir

**Context:**

The [`readdir_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir_r) function is used to read the next entry from a `DIR*` (there's also `readdir`, but that's not thread-safe). `readdir_r` takes a pointer to a user-allocated buffer to hold the output `dirent`. The manpage indicates that the size required for this buffer may be different on different systems, and provides an example of how to find a safe length at runtime:

```
len = offsetof(struct dirent, d_name) + pathconf(dirpath, _PC_NAME_MAX) + 1;
```

(warning: there is a race condition in the above, which can be avoided by using `dirfd` to get the file descriptor for the opened `DIR*` and using `fpathconf` instead of `pathconf`)

**Question:**

Looking at the manpage for [`pathconf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pathconf), it states:

> **_PC_NAME_MAX**
>   returns the maximum length of a filename in the directory path or fd that the process is allowed to create. The corresponding macro is _POSIX_NAME_MAX.

However, in the notes section, it states:

> Files with name lengths longer than the value returned for name equal to _PC_NAME_MAX may exist in the given directory.

Is this note true? If so, is the example code in the `readdir_r` man-page incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That interpretation of {NAME_MAX} does not agree with POSIX. POSIX says that implementations must treat names longer than {NAME_MAX} as an error and that a `d_name` buffer of {NAME_MAX}+1 bytes is sufficient.

An alternative (POSIX.1-2008) is to use `scandir()` which is thread-safe and abstracts this issue from the caller. Unfortunately, there is no `scandirat()` or `fscandir()` in any version of POSIX.

On many systems, it is also safe to use `readdir()` as long as the last access to the returned `struct dirent` happens-before the next call to `readdir()` (which follows from the existing requirements on the validity of the structure). I think there is little reason for POSIX not to permit this. `readdir_r()` requires quite a lot of extra code which makes things slower and more complex.

Comment: Thanks. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#4.13 : "If any pathname component is longer than {NAME_MAX}, the implementation shall consider this an error."